# Wikitude: constantly update POI information from native code?

Tags: android, geolocation, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am completely new to JavaScript and HTML but am considering Wikitude for developing an Android AR app for the ODG R-7 smartglasses. Before I invest my very limited time in learning JavaScript, I want to be as certain as possible that what I need to do can be implemented using Wikitude. If anyone could provide insight on this, I would be very grateful!

**In your view, could Wikitude be used to implement an application that does the following:**

- Information about a moving target is displayed as text on a POI. The location and information about this target is changing.
- The information, including the GPS coordinates, is received from another program in the native code. Therefore, it should be possible to pass this information to the JavaScript code and update the location and the text that is attached to the target POI each time the information message is received.

Based on what I’ve read, it’s possible to forward information from the native code to the JavaScript code. What I am worried about is the rest. I am pretty sure changing the location of the POI this way is possible, but how about constantly updating the text information attached to that POI?

If you think there is a better augmented reality SDK that could be used for this I would also be glad to hear it as well. So far the options for SDKs with geolocations and visual markers (I need both) seem slim.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Short answer: It is possible, longer answer can be found in the wikitude forum: https://support.wikitude.com/support/discussions/topics/5000084617

Answer (score 1):

You can send messages from Native Android to your Wikitude JavaScript code.

You just need to write a JavaScript function ready to receive the data and make changes. Then, call it form Android (maybe when an event has occurred) passing the data as arguments using

```
this.architectView.callJavascript("yourJSfunction(args)");
```